# Travelling with récipissé

Tags: india, france, tips-and-tricks

Can one travel outside France with a récipissé? My card has expired in June 2017 then I got a récipissé from the préfecture until 26 December 2017. Can I travel to India on this récipissé?

Comment: Are you an Indian citizen? If so, you likely cannot enter India with any other document but your Indian passport.

Comment: @GeorgeY. That's a good point, but the question relevant to the recipisse is whether the bearer will be able to use it to reenter the Schengen area (to which I think the answer is *no,* but I am not certain) and whether leaving France while the application is pending constitutes abandonment of the application (to which I think the answer may be *yes).*

Comment: @phoog yep, I'd close it as unclear as I assumed he meant "I only have recipisse and no other documents" and you interpreted it as "I have passport and recipisse, if I leave Schengen zone, will I be admitted back upon return"?

Answer (score 2):

You can travel outside of Schengen space from France and come back with a 'récépissé de demande de renouvellement de carte de séjour' that must be valid (at the time you come back).

[Comment revenir en France après être sorti de l'espace Schengen ?](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F12189)

> récépissé de demande de renouvellement de carte de séjour (en cours de
>   validité),

But :

> Attention :
>
> pour revenir dans l'espace Schengen, que votre nationalité soit
>   soumise ou pas à visa, vous devrez justifier que vous remplissez bien
>   les conditions d'entrée (ressources, etc.).